# Are there are ARM NEON instructions for signed right-shift that round toward zero?

Tags: c, arm, neon

I am trying to implement an algorithm using ARM intrinsics.

On step of the algorithm requires a right shift of a signed integer, but it needs to round negative values upwards (i.e. less negative).  For example, if shifting right by one, then -8 should give -4, but -1 should give 0.

In other words, I want something that rounds negative values towards zero instead of rounding down:

```
int rightshift(int number, unsigned int shift)
{
    return ((number < 0) ? -1 : 1) * (abs(number) >> shift);
}
```

I am not able to find a suitable function to do this in SIMD fashion. Is there a way to do this in one function call, or some trick that could be used?

Comment: there is usually no such instruction in microprocessors.

Comment: You're looking for round-up for negative numbers, and round-down for positive?  You won't get that in a single instruction, I think.  But you could add `number >> (bits - 1) & number >> (shift - 1) & 1` to the number before shifting, I think (where `bits` is `sizeof number * CHAR_BIT`).

Comment: The operation you describe is not shifting. That's why there is no such a low-level instruction.

Comment: Are you using the full range of your integer input value ?

Comment: I am trying to use int16x4_t arm type.

Comment: OK - but are you using the full range, from -32768 to +32767 ?

Comment: Yes, I use full range.

Comment: OK - so you can't use the logic above, where you shift the abs value and handle the sign separately then.

Comment: I've now written an answer and edited it to show how GCC generates Neon instructions for (a corrected version of) the algorithm in my comment.  It took a while, due to the care required to avoid out-of-range bitshifts and get everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a single-instruction shift with round-toward-zero behaviour.

However, you can do it fairly simply with a couple of shift and mask instructions.  What we need to do is to add one to the result if we started with a negative number and there is a 'carry' out (i.e. any bit to the right of the result would have been 1).

I can demonstrate this with the following pure C code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

int16_t rightshift(int number, unsigned int shift)
{
    static const size_t bits = sizeof number * CHAR_BIT;

    number += ((1<<shift) - 1) & (number >> bits-1);
    return number >> shift;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for (int i = -16; i <= 16;  ++i) {
        printf(" %3d: ", i);
        for (int j = 0;  j < 4;  ++j)
            printf("%4d", rightshift(i, j));
        puts("");
    }
}
```

This compiles to some nice branch-fee assembly, which looks amenable to inlining (especially when `shift` is a compile-time constant):

```asm
rightshift:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    movs    r3, #1
    lsls    r3, r3, r1
    subs    r3, r3, #1
    and r3, r3, r0, asr #31
    add r0, r0, r3
    asrs    r0, r0, r1
    bx  lr
```

---

To target Neon, I wrote another function, to exercise it with multiple data:

```
void do_shift(int16_t *restrict dest, const int16_t *restrict src,
              size_t count, unsigned int shift)
{
    for (size_t j = 0;  j < count;  ++j) {
        dest[j] = rightshift(src[j], shift);
    }
}
```

And a test program for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    static const int16_t src[] = {
        -32768, -32767, -32766, -32765, -32764,
        -16384, -16383, -16382, -16381, -16380,
        -8193,  -8192,  -8191,  -8190,  -8189,
        -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -10, -9,
        -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        1023, 1024, 32767,
    };
    static const size_t count = sizeof src / sizeof *src;
    int16_t dest[16][count];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16;  ++i) {
        do_shift(dest[i], src, count, i);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < count;  ++i) {
        printf("%7d: ", src[i]);
        for (int j = 0;  j < 16;  ++j)
            printf("%7d", dest[j][i]);
        puts("");
    }
}
```

I compiled this with `gcc -O3 -march=armv7 -mfpu=neon`.  I confess I'm not familiar with the Neon instructions, but the results may be instructive:

```asm
do_shift:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    cmp r2, #0
    beq .L21
    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
    ubfx    r4, r1, #1, #2
    negs    r4, r4
    movs    r5, #1
    and r4, r4, #7
    lsls    r5, r5, r3
    adds    r7, r4, #7
    subs    r6, r2, #1
    subs    r5, r5, #1
    cmp r6, r7
    sxth    r5, r5
    bcc .L8
    cmp r4, #0
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1]
    cmp r4, #1
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0]    @ movhi
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, #2]
    cmp r4, #2
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, #2]    @ movhi
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, #4]
    cmp r4, #3
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, #4]    @ movhi
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, #6]
    cmp r4, #4
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, #6]    @ movhi
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, #8]
    cmp r4, #5
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, #8]    @ movhi
    beq .L9
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, #10]
    cmp r4, #7
    ite eq
    moveq   r8, r4
    movne   r8, #6
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    it  eq
    ldrsheq r7, [r1, #12]
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, #10]   @ movhi
    itttt   eq
    andeq   r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    addeq   r6, r6, r7
    sxtheq  r6, r6
    asreq   r6, r6, r3
    it  eq
    strheq  r6, [r0, #12]   @ movhi
.L4:
    vdup.32 q10, r3
    sub lr, r2, r4
    lsls    r4, r4, #1
    movs    r7, #0
    vneg.s32    q10, q10
    adds    r6, r1, r4
    lsr ip, lr, #3
    add r4, r4, r0
    vdup.16 q12, r5
.L6:
    adds    r7, r7, #1
    adds    r6, r6, #16
    vldr    d18, [r6, #-16]
    vldr    d19, [r6, #-8]
    cmp r7, ip
    vshr.s16    q8, q9, #15
    vand    q8, q8, q12
    vadd.i16    q8, q8, q9
    vmovl.s16 q9, d16
    vmovl.s16 q8, d17
    vshl.s32    q9, q9, q10
    vshl.s32    q8, q8, q10
    vmovn.i32   d22, q9
    vmovn.i32   d23, q8
    vst1.16 {q11}, [r4]
    add r4, r4, #16
    bcc .L6
    bic r6, lr, #7
    cmp lr, r6
    add r4, r8, r6
    beq .L1
.L3:
    ldrsh   ip, [r1, r4, lsl #1]
    adds    r7, r4, #1
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, ip, asr #31
    add r6, r6, ip
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r4, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #2
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    adds    r7, r4, #3
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #4
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    adds    r7, r4, #5
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #6
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    adds    r7, r4, #7
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #8
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    add r7, r4, #9
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #10
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    add r7, r4, #11
    cmp r2, r7
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   lr, [r1, r7, lsl #1]
    add ip, r4, #12
    cmp r2, ip
    and r6, r5, lr, asr #31
    add r6, r6, lr
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, r7, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   r7, [r1, ip, lsl #1]
    adds    r4, r4, #13
    cmp r2, r4
    and r6, r5, r7, asr #31
    add r6, r6, r7
    sxth    r6, r6
    asr r6, r6, r3
    strh    r6, [r0, ip, lsl #1]    @ movhi
    bls .L1
    ldrsh   r1, [r1, r4, lsl #1]
    and r2, r5, r1, asr #31
    add r2, r2, r1
    sxth    r2, r2
    asr r3, r2, r3
    strh    r3, [r0, r4, lsl #1]    @ movhi
.L1:
    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, pc}
.L9:
    mov r8, r4
    b   .L4
.L21:
    bx  lr
.L8:
    movs    r4, #0
    b   .L3
```

There's a lot of loop unrolling which makes the code longer, but the pattern should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

To get rounding to 0 we need to add `(1 << shift) - 1` to every negative number, test for negative can be done by signed shift as Toby Speight suggested. So here the example with NEON intrinsics, easily adaptable:

```cpp
inline int32x4_t shift_right_round_zero_s32(int32x4_t vec, int shift)
{
    int32x4_t add = vandq_s32(vshrq_n_s32(vec, 31), vdupq_n_s32((1 << shift) - 1));
    return vshrq_n_s32(vaddq_s32(vec, add), shift);
}
```